# Laravel how to create a seeder based on array

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

How can I create a `laravel`-seeder based on an array?

I have an array like this:

```
$positions = array(
    array('industry_id' => '1', 'name' => 'developer'), 
    array('industry_id' => '1', 'name' => 'designer'),
    array('industry_id' => '2', 'name' => 'project manager'),
    array('industry_id' => '3', 'name' => 'manager'),
   ...etc, etc,...etc // there are like 150 entries
 )
```

So instead of doing like this

```
Position::create([
   'industry_id' => '1',
   'name' => 'developer'
]);
```

for each entry, I was hoping there might be another way to achieve that?

Comment: What exactly have you tried? The given example does not use anything from that array after all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option A)**

```
$positions = array(
    array('industry_id' => '1', 'name' => 'developer'), 
    array('industry_id' => '1', 'name' => 'designer'),
    array('industry_id' => '2', 'name' => 'project manager'),
    array('industry_id' => '3', 'name' => 'manager'),
    ....
 );

 foreach ($positions as $position) {
     Position::create([
      'industry_id' => $position['industry_id'],
      'name' => $position['name'],
    ]);
 }
```

**Option B)**

```
DB::table((new Position)->getTable())->insert($positions);
```

> Note: Insert doesn't automatically populate the timestamp columns.

Comment: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Comment: Most likely a industry with the given id that doesn't exist in the database

Answer (score 1):

you can try `insert()` by this `created_at` and `updated_at` is not automatically created so add manually

ref link https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#inserts

```php
Position::insert([
    [
        'industry_id' => '1',
        'name' => 'developer',
        "created_at" => now(),
        "updated_at" => now()
    ],
    [
        'industry_id' => '1',
        'name' => 'designer',
        "created_at" => now(),
        "updated_at" => now()
    ],
    [
        'industry_id' => '2',
        'name' => 'project manager',
        "created_at" => now(),
        "updated_at" => now()
    ],
    [
        'industry_id' => '3',
        'name' => 'manager',
        "created_at" => now(),
        "updated_at" => now()
    ],
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [foreach](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) :

```
foreach ($positions as $position) {
    Position::create(
        [
            'industry_id' => $position["industry_id"],
            'name'        => $position["name"],
        ]
    );
}
```

it's not for big array/data but it's automatically create `created_at` and `updated_at` , other way use insert like Paul's answer

Comment: Also a very useful answer